# Gesture recognition in JAVA

Tags: java, webcam, gesture, gesture-recognition

I have to make a gesture recognition App for my JAVA project, how do I proceed?

I would be using webcam to view the image.
I found certain softwares made using Python and C#, but how do I proceed in JAVA?